# What does "unknown OS" mean in SourceForge?

Tags: sourceforge

I know that stackoverflow is not the best place to ask this question but I am not sure where to ask whereas I am quite sure that someone has experienced that situation.

I have the project [BingoCards](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bingocards/?source=navbar) in sourceforge and I would like to understand what would the unknown OS probably mean in the summary statistics [see pic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6wsx73tct9xw1ur/stackoverflow_1.png?dl=0).

Comment: Just a guess: Windows Phone, Wii, XBOX, PlayStation, SmartTVs... There are several options

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I wonder about the reason for the owner of such a device to download a LibreOffice/OpenOffice extension. This would not be a surprise if there was few such counts but there are 109 in total of 432...

Comment: Since last week, the number of downloads proliferated for one of my projects, but I was wondering if those statistics were meaningful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in my experience downloads by "unknown" OS usually massively appear very soon after updating a project, plus they have very specific geography, for example, huge proportion of such downloads are from Spain, regardless of a type of downloaded software. 
Therefore, I suppose that these downloads largely reflect automatic downloads by secondary software distributors such as Softpedia, download.cnet.com et cetera.

Comment: It seems to be a reasonable explanation. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Welcome! Note, I do not mean the all "unknown OS" are automatic downloads, but seems that many.